# Does this structure have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It's a ideal form by the multiples AX,A is a ring and X is the subset of A that have least element to form the ideal .

It's a generalization of principal ideal.

by the way how to call the set X

Comment: You mean, as opposed to the ideal generated by $X$?

Comment: Isn't every ideal I of this form, by taking X=I?

Comment: Does X have a name?

Comment: Are you requiring that the generating set $X$ have minimal cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "copy-paste" of the "definition" given by M. Artin...

[image: Artin]

Comment: 332, bottom half (2nd Edition book).
And keep in mind that Artin likes to deal mostly with commutative rings, hence here once again we do not make a differentiation between left and right ideals.